# What's the purpose of sleep(long millis, int nanos)?

Tags: sleep, java

In the JDK, it's implemented as:

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos) 
throws InterruptedException {
if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
}

if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
}

if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && millis == 0)) {
    millis++;
}

sleep(millis);
}
```

which means the `nanos` argument doesn't do anything at all.

Is the idea behind it that on hardware with more accurate timing, the JVM for it can provide a better implementation for it?

Comment: well, it does *something*, it bumps millis if it's over half a ms or if ms is zero.

Comment: well, yeah not *nothing* ... but it's pretty much worthless.

Comment: Source code is from Open JDK?

Comment: Is that implementation for Solaris, Linux, Windows?

Comment: This is Sun's (Oracle's) JDK on Linux. No idea what it is on others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A regular OS doesn't have a fine grained enough resolution to sleep for nanoseconds at a time.  However, [real time operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) exist, where scheduling an event to take place at an exact moment in time is critical and latencies for many operations are VERY low. An ABS system is one example of a RTOS. Sleeping for nanoseconds is much more useful on such systems than on normal OSes where the OS can't reliably sleep for any period less than 15ms.

However, having two separate JDKs is no solution. Hence on Windows and Linux the JVM will make a best attempt to sleep for *x* nanoseconds.

Comment: The 15ms minimum you are referring to is only true for Windows. On Linux you can do 1ms sleeps. But even on Windows, you can use [`timeBeginPeriod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624.aspx) to increase the timer resolution, which will allow you to sleep for smaller intervals, too. This however is a global setting (affecting all running programs), and will increase CPU usage, power consumption, and, `it can also reduce overall system performance`. It might in fact have significant effects on programs that do `sleep(1)`, relying on the 15ms interval default.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a future-proof addition, for when we all have petaflop laptops and we routinely specify delays in nanoseconds. Meanwhile if you specify a nanosecond delay, you get a millisecond delay.

When hardware improves and the JVM follows, the app will not need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with future proofing is backward compatibily.  This method has worked this way for so long that if you want sub-micro-second delays you have to use different methods.

For comparison,

```
 Object.wait(millis, nano);
```

Comment: That's implemented exactly like `sleep(...)`. it just calls `wait(millis)`, unless `millis==0 || nanos>=500000`, in which case it calls `wait(millis+1)`